# ListView Filter filters correctly but shows wrong result

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-adapter, searchview

I have a custom `Adapter` that I use to display custom objects in a `ListView`. Furthermore, I used a `SearchView` that allows me search through the `ListView` and filter out results. However, I have noticed some strange behavior when I try to enter a search. As long as I search for an item that is on the list, an item will show up in the filter - however , items are always displayed from the top of the list. If there are 10 items in the list and a search produces 5 matches then the result will show the first 5 items in the list instead of the 5 actual matches. For example, consider this list with 6 motorcycle helmets on it:

- Bell
- Icon
- Harley Davidson
- Joe Rocket
- Shoei
- Thor

If I search for "ho", the resulting list should be as follows:

- S**ho**ei
- T**ho**r

However, the list that I get is the first two items:

- Bell
- Icon

I can't figure out why the search isn't working properly. Any help would be appreciated. My code is shown below...

**HelmetActivity.java**

```
public class HelmetActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

    private Menu menu;
    private ListView listView;
    private HelmetAdapter helmetAdapter;
    private List<Helmet> arrayList;
    private SearchManager searchManager;
    private SearchView searchView;
    private MenuItem searchMenuItem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.helmet_activity);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setElevation(0);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.helmet_listview);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<Helmet>();
        listView.setLongClickable(true);
        helmetAdapter = new HelmetAdapter(this, R.layout.helmet, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(helmetAdapter);

        arrayList.add(new Helmet("Bell"));
        arrayList.add(new Helmet("Icon"));
        arrayList.add(new Helmet("Harley Davidson"));
        arrayList.add(new Helmet("Joe Rocket"));
        arrayList.add(new Helmet("Shoei"));
        arrayList.add(new Helmet("Thor"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        this.menu = menu;
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.helmet_activity_menu, menu);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(
                Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(
                getComponentName()));
        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(HelmetActivity.this);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
    {
        helmetAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

        return true;
    }
}
```

**HelmetAdapter.java**

```
public class HelmetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Helmet> implements Filterable
{
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    private List<Helmet> helmetList;
    private List<Helmet> filteredHelmetList;
    private HelmetFilter helmetFilter;

    public HelmetAdapter (Context pContext, int pResource, List<Helmet> helmetList)
    {
        super (pContext, pResource, helmetList);
        resource = pResource;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from (pContext);
        context = pContext;
        this.helmetList = helmetList;
        this.filteredHelmetList = helmetList;
        getFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView (final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        if (convertView == null)
        { convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false); }

        String uri;
        int imageResource;
        Drawable image;
        Helmet helmet = getItem (position);
        TextView hName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.h_name);
        hName.setText(helmet.getName());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    { return filteredHelmetList.size(); }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter()
    {
        if (helmetFilter == null)
        {
            helmetFilter = new HelmetFilter();
        }

        return helmetFilter;
    }

    private class HelmetFilter extends Filter
    {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering (CharSequence constraint)
        {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0)
            {
                ArrayList<Helmet> temporaryHelmetList = new ArrayList<Helmet>();
                for (Helmet helmet : helmetList)
                {
                    if (helmet.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString()
                            .toLowerCase()))
                    {
                        temporaryHelmetList.add(helmet);
                    }
                }
                filterResults.count = temporaryHelmetList.size();
                filterResults.values = temporaryHelmetList;
            }
            else
            {
                filterResults.count = helmetList.size();
                filterResults.values = helmetList;
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
        {
            filteredHelmetList = (ArrayList<Helmet>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**Helmet.java**

```
public class Helmet
{

    public Helmet (String name)
    {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String     name;

    public String getName ()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (String pName)
    {
        this.name = pName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks to me like your problem most likely lies in the `getView(..)` method of your adapter.

This line in particular -

```
Helmet helmet = getItem (position);
```

If you are returning the item in your original array of helmets then that would explain why you're getting the results you are. However, I can't be sure because I don't see your `getItem(..)` method posted in your code. If this is indeed the case then of course you would want to be returning your filtered results here (if there are any) instead of those from the unfiltered list.

Comment: I ended up modifying my `getItem` and `getView` methods and now it works. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @Willis What did you do??I have exactly the same problem like you! Thanks in advance!